# Convergence of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{\sin k}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Is this series convergent? I met it when I was studying some fractals.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{\sin k}{k}$$

Comment: I highly doubt it.  Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n-1$$

Comment: Note that this is not a series ; its main term doesn't depend on just $n$.

Comment: Not really a series, since the terms are different depending on $n$. But still a nice question

Comment: For $n=50$, the sum is $-3.5\times 10^{10}$.  For $n=51$, the sum is $-1.5\times 10^{10}$.  For $n=52$, the sum is $5.9\times 10^{10}$.  Convergence is, in my mind, very doubtful.

Answer (score 5):

A very long comment that is made to make you lose faith in the convergence of your limit ; I didn't actually prove the fact that it diverges though. For $x \in \mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk \frac{x^k}k &= \sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk\int_0^x t^{k-1} \, \mathrm dt \\
 &= \int_0^x \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk t^{k-1}  \right) \, \mathrm dt \\
 &= \int_0^x \left( \frac 1t \left[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk t^k - 1 \right] \right) \mathrm dt \\
 &= \int_0^x \frac{(1+t)^n-1}{t} \, \mathrm dt \\
 &= \int_0^x \frac{(1+t)^n - 1}{(1+t)-1} \, \mathrm dt \\
 &= \int_0^x \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+t)^k \, \mathrm dt \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^x (1+t)^k \, \mathrm dt \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[ \frac{(1+x)^{k+1} - 1}{k+1} \right] \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \frac{(1+x)^k - 1}{k} \right].
\end{align}
$$
hence letting $x = e^i$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \frac{(1+e^i)^k - 1}{k} \right] = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk \frac{e^{ik}}k = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk \frac{\cos k}{k} \right) + i \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk \frac{\sin k}{k} \right) 
$$
If the series for $\sin$ and $\cos$ would converge, so would the series 
$$
\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(1+e^i)^k - 1}{k}.
$$
The main term of this series doesn't go to zero because
$$
\left| \frac{(1+e^i)^k - 1}{k} \right| \ge \frac{|1+e^i|^k - 1}{k} \ge \frac{(1.75)^k - 1}{k} \to \infty.
$$
(I used the fact that $|1+e^i| \approx 1.755165...$ see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Abs%5B1%2bCos%5B1%5D%20%2b%20i%20Sin%5B1%5D%5D).) So we know that either the real part or the imaginary part diverges. I think it's enough to lose faith in having either one converge since they behave similarly (and the series considered isn't just divergent, its main term goes to infinity...)

Hope that helps,

Comment: I always forget how to align stuff because I use \begin{gather*} \begin{aligned} instead but that doesn't work here. Thanks Milind!

Comment: Nice, but "A very long comment that is made to make you lose faith in the divergence of your limit." Shouldn't "divergence" read "convergence," or you believe the $\sin$-version converges?

Comment: God. My brain is switching everything around this morning!

Answer (score 2):

Before taking the limit, the sum has an expression form in terms of hypergeometric functions:

$$
\sum _{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{\sin k }{k} = 
-\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i} n \left(e^{2 i} \, _3F_2\left(1,1,1-n;2,2;-e^i\right)-\, _3F_2\left(1,1,1-n;2,2;-e^{-i}\right)\right)
$$

Now you just need to study the asymptotics of such functions, namely, do they decay fast enough as the thrid argument goes to $-\infty$.  I think you could find these properties in the usual references about special functions (DLMF or Abramowitz and Stegun), and that would suffice as a proof.  I can certainly say that they grow unboundedly as the third argument becomes increasingly negative, but you'd need some asymptotic bounds to finish off a proof.